# Web Worker effect on max http connections on per browser per domain

Tags: javascript, web-worker, httpconnection

This question is an extension to [Max HTTP Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985431/max-parallel-http-connections-in-a-browser)

What kind of impact Web worker brings to this equation, would the limit increase? As in 3 web workers would be able to send (3 * browser limit) request?

Comment: @rbrundritt What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Need to call a web service 2,000 times as fast as possible from JavaScript. Using the UI thread i'm lucky to get 25 queries per second. I tried spreading out the calls across multiple web workers and managed to get 132 queries per second. But only tested in a couple browsers from localhost and haven't tried hosting app on web. Wanted to see if anyone has done extensive testing on this. Couldn't find any info on the web about this. I know making this many calls to a web service isn't ideal but it is a limitation of the service which I can change. The service expects a high volume of calls.

Comment: @rbrundritt  What is your findings? I realize this question is a long time ago.

Comment: I never found anything official, but in my tests I found that this does seem to work in both Edge and Chrome. I didn't do any extensive testing in other browsers.

Comment: Is this still true? I did a test described here (https://stackoverflow.com/q/72222033/3269537) and wasn't able to replicate. We're you using http2 by any chance?